# How detect the presence of one or more "empty areas" in Wav audio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wav

I am a Chinese, and my English is very bad, and hope you can understand.

I need to check if the wave waveform of Wave audio has "empty area".

[image: empty area in wav file]

I load wav with "sample_rate, X = scipy.io.wavfile.read(path)".

X is a numpy array, you know it.

From the exported txt file, the array is about 50K lines, and the "empty area" data to be detected is a large number of repeated 0. You also know it.

In the example I found in Google, they used a for loop.
Just like this:

```
sample_rate, X = scipy.io.wavfile.read(path)
    c=0
    for i in X:
        if i==0:
            c=c+1
    if c>100: #
        print("it has empty area")
```

Just a simple count.

So if there is only one "empty area", it maybe worked , but my audio has multiple "empty area", how should I write the code?

Comment: A `for` loop is usually for multiple instances of something. Please include the code you found on Google, or as you have it right now, so people can give you a better answer.

Comment: Just loop through your data and count the number of 0s you see. Any time you see a non-zero value, reset the counter and report the count if it is above the minimum length you need. Count the number of reports, and now you have the number of empty areas.

Comment: @JochemKuijpers you mean two counter, one for 0s, one for  empty areas.....en  I think I allready know how to do.thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, with some expression similar to,

```
(?:(?:0{4}\s){8}){1,}
```

you'd be able to remove those lines of zeros, that I'm guessing, they might look like:

```
import re

regex = r"(?:(?:0{4}\s){8}){1,}"
string = """
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
1000 0000 0100 0100 112b 0000 2256 0000
0200 1000 6461 7461 96a5 0400 0000 feff
0000 feff ffff fdff ffff feff 0100 fdff
ffff feff ffff 0000 0000 fcff 0000 feff
0000 fcff 0000 fdff 0000 fdff 0000 fdff
ffff fdff 0000 ffff 0200 feff 0100 ffff
0200 fdff 0100 feff 0300 feff 0200 fdff
0200 feff 0300 ffff 0300 fcff 0300 feff
0500 fdff 0300 feff 0400 feff 0300 feff
0000 fdff 0400 fdff 0400 fdff 0500 feff
0600 fdff 0600 faff 0500 fcff 0600 fdff
0600 faff 0700 f9ff 0700 f8ff 0900 faff
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0900 f8ff 0800 f8ff 0b00 f8ff 0800 f6ff
0b00 f5ff 0e00 f4ff 1100 f4ff 1100 f1ff
1600 eeff 1900 edff 1900 e9ff 2100 e5ff
2a00 d6ff 3c00 b7ff ad00 be00 e300 fd00
e5ff b0ff 8ffe abfe 1b02 bdff 8dfd caff
bd00 ccfd 44ff ab00 68ff 8b00 0201 89ff
0d01 5700 05fb f100 0004 a203 c4ff e2fb
cbfd f500 5700 0101 8f02 8a03 9700 6ffe
5cfe 0900 c1ff 7bfc 56ff 3f03 28ff 39fd
13fd 2bfe 7802 8204 ee00 0903 24fe 32fa
6e01 c605 ecfe 9ffe acfc baff 7304 5b03
ef00 07fb eefb a8ff 1604 de02 f3fb d4fb
1302 5101 a001 8bff 3504 88ff 89ff d100
be04 d202 3ffa 89fa 78fe b902 c6ff e9ff
8802 dafe 5ffb 9dfd 4dfc ab02 2f04 f101

"""

print(re.sub(regex, "", string, re.DOTALL))
```

#### Output

```
1000 0000 0100 0100 112b 0000 2256 0000
0200 1000 6461 7461 96a5 0400 0000 feff
0000 feff ffff fdff ffff feff 0100 fdff
ffff feff ffff 0000 0000 fcff 0000 feff
0000 fcff 0000 fdff 0000 fdff 0000 fdff
ffff fdff 0000 ffff 0200 feff 0100 ffff
0200 fdff 0100 feff 0300 feff 0200 fdff
0200 feff 0300 ffff 0300 fcff 0300 feff
0500 fdff 0300 feff 0400 feff 0300 feff
0000 fdff 0400 fdff 0400 fdff 0500 feff
0600 fdff 0600 faff 0500 fcff 0600 fdff
0600 faff 0700 f9ff 0700 f8ff 0900 faff
0900 f8ff 0800 f8ff 0b00 f8ff 0800 f6ff
0b00 f5ff 0e00 f4ff 1100 f4ff 1100 f1ff
1600 eeff 1900 edff 1900 e9ff 2100 e5ff
2a00 d6ff 3c00 b7ff ad00 be00 e300 fd00
e5ff b0ff 8ffe abfe 1b02 bdff 8dfd caff
bd00 ccfd 44ff ab00 68ff 8b00 0201 89ff
0d01 5700 05fb f100 0004 a203 c4ff e2fb
cbfd f500 5700 0101 8f02 8a03 9700 6ffe
5cfe 0900 c1ff 7bfc 56ff 3f03 28ff 39fd
13fd 2bfe 7802 8204 ee00 0903 24fe 32fa
6e01 c605 ecfe 9ffe acfc baff 7304 5b03
ef00 07fb eefb a8ff 1604 de02 f3fb d4fb
1302 5101 a001 8bff 3504 88ff 89ff d100
be04 d202 3ffa 89fa 78fe b902 c6ff e9ff
8802 dafe 5ffb 9dfd 4dfc ab02 2f04 f101
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/LhBRKZ/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/LhBRKZ/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---